# Как перебрать строку, отсортировать и построить новую

Tags: php

Мне приходит строка вот в таком виде:

```
2213:0:711.75:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:185.535:397:0:0:0;
5193:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:464.07:558:0:92.535:0;
```

Строка построена в таком формате:

(**Подстрока1**(**ИД устройства**:значение1:значение2:значениеN);**Подстрока2**(**ИД устройства**:значение1:значение2:значениеN);)

Мне нужно, каким то образом просуммировать все значения для устройства 2213, затем просуммировать все значения для устройства 5193, после чего **СРАВНИТЬ** эти значения, и построить новую строку в порядке возрастания.

Если посчитать вручную, то сумма значений для 2213 будет 1294,285, а для 5193 будет 1114,605

С этого я понятно, что сумма значений для устройства 2213 Больше чем для 5193, значит исходная строка должна быть такой:

```
5193:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:464.07:558:0:92.535:0;
2213:0:711.75:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:185.535:397:0:0:0;
```

Соответственно нужно сравнивать строки не только по 2 оборудованиям но и по N оборудованию, так как входящая строка с которой необходимо работать может включать не 2 устройства а несколько.

Помогите пожалуйста это реализовать

Comment: А не проще принять строку в нормальном формате `JSON`?

Comment: Ну мне приходит именно строка вот в таком формате как я описал, а дальше можно с ней работать. Если можете предложить скрипт то было бы отлично!

Comment: разделите строку просто в вопросе так что бы видно было что к чему

Comment: Честно говоря я максимально попытался подробно обьяснить. То есть смотрите: приходит строка скажем $string она содержит подстроки, которые разделены между собой сиволом ;  Каждая из этих подстрок имеет элементы, которые разделены между собой : Первый элемент в этой подстроке это ИД оборудования, а дальше значения.

Comment: Сначала разбиваете ее по `;` с помощью explode, потом идете по этому массиву, разбиваете элемент так же explode по `:`. Когда первое поле совпало с требуемым номером в нужную переменную суммируете то что хотели просуммировать. подправляете в массивах то что там должно изменится, собираете обратно в строки implode

Comment: Вот эта часть строки что из себя представляет? `2213:0:711.75:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:185.535:397:0:0:0`?

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan, Эта строка это подстрока со значениям, где первый элемент это номер оборудования, а дальше все его значения которые необходимо просумировать

Comment: два эксплода, суммирование, сортировка, запись. выше ведь написали уже, в чем сложность до у вас заключается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот допустим ваша строка

```
$data = "2213:0:711.75:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:185.535:397:0:0:0;5193:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:464.07:558:0:92.535:0;";
```

Очевидно, сначала следует ее разделить по `;`, для чего используем `explode()` и выкидываем последний пустой элемент . Теперь у нас есть набор строк.

```
$lines = explode(";", $data);
array_pop($lines);
```

Каждую строку следует разделить по `:`, и, откинув `id`, посчитать сумму.

```
$data = [];
foreach($lines as $l){
    $x = explode(":", $l);
    array_shift($x);
    $data[$l] = array_sum($x);
}
```

при этом нам тут нет смысла хранить детали о строке, как `id` и т.п. Нужна только сумма и исходный вид строки. Так что сумма становится значением, а строка - ключом.

Далее используем `asort()` чтобы отсортировать промежуточный массив по сумме, сохраняя ключи:

```
asort($data); // или arsort в обратном порядке
```

И осталось склеить в кучу ключи полученного массива. Используем `array_keys`  и `implode`:

```
$result = implode(";", array_keys($data));
```

останется в конец дописать `;`

Comment: следует заметить. что при совпадении сумм порядок следование будет не определен.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, единственное то что необходимо это просортировать по порядку возрастания, как вы видите из примера строка для 2213 имеет сумму больше чем 5193, значит  result должна вывести строку где сначала будет 5193 а затем 2213. Можете подправить свой ответ?

Comment: @WhoIsDT `array_reverse` добавьте при вызове `implode` да и все дела.

Comment: погорячился с реверсом, просто `arsort` юзайте да и все.

Comment: Спасибо! Ваше решение лаконичное и понятно, я внедрил и оно работает. Я задавал вопрос так как пробовал все через циклы но у меня такими дебрями все шло что я запутался! Ваше решение возьму за пособие))

Comment: @WhoIsDT за пособие лучше справку по пхп возьмите :) и в частности про [функции работы с массивами](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php)